# Unable to update qty on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to update quantity on cart page but not updated.

Please help me how to solve this issue ?

Comment: have throw any error?

Comment: no i have not getting any error on cart page but it reloads and not update quantity on update button.

Comment: that may form_key issue ..

Comment: yes @Vicky Dev gives me form key solution and it works fine. now i can update cart qty. thanks for suggestions buddy.

Comment: Just ways check  always   if at controller then code `if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }` exit then  you  need send   form_key  at  this controller for access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `formkey` block to your cart page like below:

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

So your cart page would look like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Shopping cart template
 *
 * @see Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart
 */
?>
<div class="cart">
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart') ?></h1>
        <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
        <ul class="checkout-types">
        <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
            <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
            <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
                <col width="1" />
                <col />
                <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />

            <?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"></th>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Move to Wishlist') ?></span></th>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Unit Price') ?></span></th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                        <th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="50" class="a-right">
                            <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
                            <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
                            <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                            <input type="hidden" id="update_cart_action_container" />
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                Event.observe(window, 'load', function()
                                {
                                    // Internet Explorer (lt 8) does not support value attribute in button elements
                                    $emptyCartButton = $('empty_cart_button');
                                    $cartActionContainer = $('update_cart_action_container');
                                    if ($emptyCartButton && $cartActionContainer) {
                                        Event.observe($emptyCartButton, 'click', function()
                                        {
                                            $emptyCartButton.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action_temp');
                                            $cartActionContainer.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action');
                                            $cartActionContainer.setValue('empty_cart');
                                        });
                                    }

                                });
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')</script>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="cart-collaterals">
        <div class="col2-set">
            <div class="col-1">
                <!--Cash Back Information-->
                   <?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                    $cashback = $quote->getCashback();
                    $cashback_discount = $quote->getCashbackDiscount();

            if(($cashback == Scommerce_Cashback_Model_Validator::cash_back_eligible) && ($cashback_discount)>0 && Mage::helper("cashback")->getEnabled()): ?>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;margin-bottom:10px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="padding:3px 9px;color:#ff0000"><strong><?php echo $this->__(Mage::helper("cashback")->getTitleMessage()) ?></strong></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" align="left" style="padding:3px 9px;color:#ff0000">
                            <?php echo $this->__(Mage::helper("cashback")->getQualifyingMessage(),  Mage::helper("core")->formatPrice($cashback_discount,true), Mage::helper("cashback")->getValidityMonth());?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php endif;?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
                <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totals">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
            <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
            <ul class="checkout-types">
            <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Hope this works for you.**

Comment: Good catch @Vicky

Comment: Inspite having form_key on form, i am unable to update cart quantity.